# Please help me identify this connector

Tags: connector, identification

This is an 11-way connector pair from inside a standalone induction hob. It comprises a cable-mounted female part and a PCB mounted male part.

[image: cable photograph 1]

[image: cable photograph 2]

[image: cable photograph 3]

(Corrected due to sloppy original measuring - thanks @Passerby) Pitch is 2.5mm  and pin length appears to be around 3.3mm. The female part is about 4mm wide and 8mm tall. Does anyone recognise this system?

Comment: Try Molex - they make em like this.

Comment: Thanks Andy - do you have a range name / number as a starting point? No worries if not, wouldn't be the first time I have trawled their catalogue!

Comment: @OleksandrR. The housing seems a lot smaller than that.

Comment: Are you sure its 2.54 and not slightly smaller?

Comment: @Passerby I think you're right - I was seeing what I wanted to see. More diligent measuring (outer pin edge to outer pin edge less measured width of pin / (numPositions - 1)) gave 2.5mm. Looks like it is the JST XH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without precise measurements it's a little hard to tell, but I am pretty sure that its a JST XH series connector. A datasheet for these connectors can be found [here](http://datasheet.octopart.com/XHP-4-JST-datasheet-8325564.pdf).

The OP has since tested and confirmed this to be the correct part.

Comment: If OP's measurements of 2.54 are true, then these are not a match.

Comment: @Passerby Why exactly? The only measurements provided are the pitch (which matches) and the pin length (which OP claims are only 3.3mm long but looking at the photos they seem a bit longer)

Comment: @jms taking a look at the datasheet you link, the pitch is 2.5, not 2.54mm. My mistake, but your answer looks correct allowing for that.

Comment: @stefandz To be honest I didn't trust in the precision of your measurements, as anything close to 2.5 mm is easily interpreted as 0.1". I looked at the photo and compared it to stuff in my parts box, then double checked with the datasheet.

Comment: Because 2.5mm is not 0.1" or 2.54mm, and even 2 contacts will be stretched or bent to fit, let alone 11. Anyone attempting to use 0.1" headers on 2.5mm connections will quickly see a problem, and it happens often as JST is as popular as 0.1" types.

Comment: And that's why I asked op to clarify, as that little spacing difference matters alot

Comment: @Passerby Absolutely true, and I worded my reply quite badly. I should have said "which matches assuming less than perfect accuracy of measurement". I was going to, but the edit time limit caught up with me.